# AutoIncrement ID Number (Works with Sorting)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Morning,

I'm constructing a table and I'd like to assign each entry a unique ID number that autoincrements as new values are entered into the table.  Here's a sample table to give a visual:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| ID | First Name | Last Name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | John       | Smith     |
|  2 | Steve      | Wozniak   |
|  3 | Steve      | Jobs      |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

In the above table, if I enter a 4th person, what I would like to happen is that the ID is automatically generated (in this case as 4).  I've tried an in cell formula such as:

```
=Row([@ID])-1
```

This works until you sort the table, in which case the ID numbers get all scrambled up.  I'd like to calculate what the row number should be, but then keep that value constant.  Any ideas?

Comment: You will need vba to assign the new number with the insertions so the value remains static.  Formulas are live and will not retain the value upon sorting.

Comment: I figured that might be the case.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Depending on the context, you could use an MS access table to store your data, it has an Autonumber datatype which has an additional advantage that on delete the assigned ID will not be re-used (in VBA this might require some effort). Also you can create a connection to the table from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static increment key, you should use a code like this in your output worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 Then
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Row - 1
End If

End Sub
```

If you just want a unique key that isn't actually incrementing based on previous one, you can use a formula like `=SUM(CODE(MID(B2&C2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B2&C2))),1)))` in your A2 cell (closing with CSE) and pull down. However, if you extend a formula too much it will affect your sheet's performance.